# Arbitrary bound of $L^{p}$ norm

Tags: measure-theory

If $f\in L^{p}(\Omega)$ then is it always true that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $A\subset\Omega$ with $|A|<\delta$ then,
\begin{align}
\int_{A}|f|^{p}dx<\varepsilon^{p}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Hints: Suppose this is  not true. Then there exist sets $A_n$ and a number $\epsilon >0$ such that $m(A_n) <\frac  1 {2^{n}}$ and $\int |f|^{p} >\epsilon$ for all $n$. Let $A=\lim \sup A_n$. Then $m(A)=0$. Apply Fatou' Lemma to $\int |f|^{p} I_{A_n^{c}}$ to conclude that $\int_A |f|^{p} \geq \epsilon$. This is  contradiction since $m(A)=0$.

Alternative proof: There exists a simple function $g \in L^{p}$ such that $\int|f-g|^{p} <\epsilon$. So it is enough to prove this for simple functions. This case is quite elementary.